# Firefox problem with hybrid fluid layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on this layout (Vertical centered,fluid middle div with, fixed heights)
http://jsfiddle.net/chchrist/uyzJj/13/

My problem is that in Firefox the #bluebox's position isn't relative to the div#wrapper. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

On `#wrapper` changing `display: table-cell` to `float: left` will solve your problem.
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/uyzJj/18/

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Option 2**

On `#superWrapper` changing `display: table` to `display: block` will solve your relative problem.

Comment: I need the #wrapper's height to be 100%. Setting float left fixes the problem but removes the height.

Comment: @chchrist: In the example I am not seeing the difference, but try adding #wrapper {height: 100%;}.

Comment: The black border must take up 80% of the screen. I've given 80% to the superwrapper and giving 100% to the #wrapper when floated takes its element's height.

Comment: @chchrist: I have had a look and as I said the only way to fix your relative positioning issue is to use one of the two options in my answer above. The second problem regarding a fluid layout, I think you will need to post another question with the fix applied asking for help with fluid layouts and filling divs 100%.